# Parse error when writing a factor function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I only started learning Haskell a few days ago, and I am currently trying to code a function that returns the factors of any number x. Based on my limited knowledge of the syntax thus far, this is what I have produced

```
[if x mod i = 0 then i else succ i | i <- [1..x]]
```

However, this doesn't work. It produces a **parse error on input 'if'**. I have tried changing the arguments and defining i outside of the function, but it always produces the same error, which makes me think that it is most likely some kind of syntax error. Any help or advice regarding the syntax and/or defining the function correctly would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Iirc, you need to have something before the if that says what will be produced from the comprehension.

Comment: Are you doing this in ghci or is this in a file?

Comment: This is in GHCi

Comment: Are you typing this into GHCi or a Haskell file? In the latter case, can you show the entire code? When I try to run your code, I get a syntax error because you used `=` instead of `==` and a type error because you didn't use backticks around `mod`, but nothing about `if`. The `if` seems perfectly fine where it is.

Comment: I get `parse error in if statement: missing required then and else clauses`, which is caused by the `=`.

Comment: That code sample there so far is literally my entire code, done in GHCi. I named the function factors and have tried it both with the arguments x and i and only with the argument x.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using `mod` function as an infix operator, you need to surround it in backquotes. The operator to compare equality is not `=` but `==` . The error free rewrite of your code is:

```
getFactors x = [if x `mod` i == 0 then i else succ i | i <- [1..x]]
```